# Find all instance types compatible with AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-ami

I would like to make an API call or use a CLI request (or multiple ones) that returns all instance types compatible with a given AMI (ami-0d59bcc339de8a2ab - Debian Buster ARM64). Here is my solution:

Find out the parameters of the AMI (CPU architecture and virtualization type)

```
aws ec2 describe-images  --image-ids ami-0d59bcc339de8a2ab
```

List the machine types that meet the requirements of the AMI

```
aws ec2 get-instance-types-from-instance-requirements \
    --architecture-types ARCHITECTURE_TYPE \
    --virtualization-types VIRTUALIZATION_TYPE \
    --instance-requirements "VCpuCount={Min=1},MemoryMiB={Min=1024}" \
    --region eu-west-1 \
    --query InstanceTypes \
    --output text
```

But trying to launch some instances from the list (e.g. `c7g.4xlarge`)  I get the following message:

```
Error: creating EC2 Instance: UnsupportedOperation: The instance configuration for this AWS Marketplace product is not supported. Please see the AWS Marketplace site for more information about supported instance types, regions, and operating systems.
```

I have also filtered them by availability zone, but this doesn't help.

I know that it is possible in the Launch Instance Wizard ([old version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/launching-instance.html)*) where unsupported instances are marked, but I am not interested in such manual solutions.

Should I consider any other parameters, that are vital to compatibility?

*Strange things: lists of available machines differ in old and new versions of the Wizard.

Comment: I was looking for a way to query what instance types work with a certain AMI. In the launch instance wizard I see what I need: t2.micro but in the output of your get-instance-types-from-instance-requirements above for x86_64 and hvm I don't see t2.micro listed. Curious. Hopefully someone figures something out for this.